# Inserting unicode message using sqlalchemy and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert a string that has smiley face emojis into a MySQL database.  I have the following test that throws an exception.  How do I get past this error?

Here is the test:

```
def test_write_unicode(self):
    db_schema = "testing"
    db_url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(drivername='mysql', host=selah.db_host,
        database=db_schema,
        query={ 'read_default_file' : selah.db_config })
    db_eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(name_or_url=db_url)
    table_name = 'test_write_unicode'
    db_eng.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0}".format(table_name))
    db_eng.execute("CREATE TABLE {0} (message text) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4".format(table_name))

    wierd_message = u"It's all about jimmy from stater bros.  "
    db_eng.execute("INSERT INTO {} (message) VALUES (%s)".format(table_name), wierd_message)
```

Here is my db_config file:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
[client]
user=selah
password=xxxx
```

Here is the error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/selah/Code/selahwork/test_sqlalchemy.py", line 39, in test_write_unicode
    db_eng.execute("INSERT INTO {} (message) VALUES (%s)".format(table_name), wierd_message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1614, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 662, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 805, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1027, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 324, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 278, in literal
    return self.escape(o, self.encoders)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 208, in unicode_literal
    return db.literal(u.encode(unicode_literal.charset))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 39-41: ordinal not in range(256)
```

EDIT:
Here is my successful test :)

```
def test_write_unicode(self):
    db_schema = "testing"
    db_url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(drivername='mysql', host=selah.db_host,
        database=db_schema,
        query={ 'read_default_file' : selah.db_config, 'charset': 'utf8mb4' })
    db_eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(name_or_url=db_url)
    table_name = 'test_write_unicode'
    db_eng.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0}".format(table_name))
    db_eng.execute("CREATE TABLE {0} (message text) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4".format(table_name))

    wierd_message = u"It's all about jimmy from stater bros.  "
    db_eng.execute("INSERT INTO {} (message) VALUES (%s)".format(table_name), wierd_message)
    res = db_eng.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_name))
    self.assertEqual(res.first()[0], wierd_message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as setting the storage collation, you need to tell the MySQL DBAPI to use UTF-8 for the connection charset. Otherwise MySQL typically defaults to `latin1_swedish_ci` (ISO-8859-1).

The connection charset is usually set using `charset=utf8mb4` in the [connection string](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-unicode) but I imagine `URL(query={'charset': 'utf8mb4'})` would probably work also.